# Ios Firebase fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I run my program and it crashes as soon as the simulator turns on.  The message before it prints before crashing is below:

> for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/DrewGelinas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/97591C46-0149-4951-BDA6-FB0C063E396C/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>       (lldb)

The code I am running is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let myuser = Auth.auth().currentUser

        let userInfo = ref.child("Users").child((myuser?.uid)!)
        userInfo.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            //get the current users credentials
            self.userNo = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "/PhoneNo").value as! String
        })
    }
```

The error is happening on the `let userInfo =` line

Comment: Please show the structure of your db in firebase

Comment: Also there should be a description about the reason of the error shown in the console, please share that part of the error as well , you can search `reason` in your console when this error occurs, this will give us a better idea about the error

Comment: And your app runs well when you comment this code out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing your `uid` with a force unwrap (`!`), which is leading to this crash.

My guess is that you don't currently have a user logged into `Auth`.

Refactor to remove the bang with something like this:

```
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        guard let myUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let userInfo = ref.child("Users").child(myUserId)
        userInfo.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            //get the current users credentials
            self.userNo = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "/PhoneNo").value as! String
        })
```

Guard statments mean that if that value DOESN'T exist, the code simply stops there, and thus you'd never try to observe a user that doesn't exist in your Auth.

Comment: Without further context, I’d think that as well. Though the error shown isn’t related in any way. Chances are he is misguided.